# Supermicro X11DPi-NT motherboard. Pinout for JD1 to connect external speaker

Tags: supermicro

I have a Supermicro X11DPi-NT motherboard, and having trouble connecting an external speaker. JD1 is supposed be the conector for the external speaker, but I am having trouble finding the pinout. If anybody has this information, please post.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's in the manual... [PDF](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C620/MNL-1773.pdf), page 11 & 12.

Comment: My manual page 11 shows location of JD1. Page 12 gives the following        JD1
Speaker/buzzer header (use in conjunction with an external speaker/buzzer) (optional)

Comment: @CountryRabbit And? What more do you want? The polarity does not matter. If it does not work one way, then try the other.

Comment: My confusion I was looking at thee wrong connector. Thank you for your patience.